# Is it possible to auto complete relative paths in VSCode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

One of the features of the `atom` editor that has kept me using it for so long is when I am doing modular imports of ES6 style classes in my local project structure.

Typing something like

`import './SomeDir/'`

would result in an intellisense/autocomplete panel showing a list of files and folders in that path.

I was surprised that `VSCode` didn't do this out of the box, but I'm now wondering if there is just something I must enable to get it working. Or perhaps there is an outstanding issue at their github page that I could start following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension has been completed and is [available here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) and works very well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a current feature of VS Code, but it would be a slick one.